# Linux Busybox GDB installation Error "rerun with a POSIX shell"

Tags: linux, gdb, busybox

I am new to linux. My device is running busybox linux. I am trying to install gdb on it so I can live debug the crash. I was following the instructions below for installation.

http://www.gdbtutorial.com/tutorial/how-install-gdb

1. The first method uses the command below. But my busybox doesn't even have apt-get built in... Searched /bin and /usr/bin folder, doesn't exsit.

   $ sudo apt-get install gdb
2. Then I followed the second method of "Download source code of GDB, compile it and install."

   ```
    $ wget "http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.11.tar.gz"
    $ tar -xvzf gdb-7.11.tar.gz
    $ cd gdb-7.11
    gdb-7.11$ ./configure
   ```

But when I ran ./configure, I got the error below:

```
~/gdb-7.11# ./configure
sed: write error
configure: error: cannot create configure.lineno; rerun with a POSIX shell
```

Comment: I'd guess that the ./configure script is trying to use a utility that busybox does not provide. The error message is not very helpful. You might need to look in the script to see how it is using sed. Frankly, I suspect your problems are only just beginning ;)

Comment: Isn't busybox usually used for low-memory devices? I don't think can build gdb on these.

Comment: What shell are you using? I've seen this error while using zsh instead of bash.